# Como informar nome de arquivo PDF para download usando IText/Lowagie e Primefaces?

Tags: java, primefaces, jsf-2.2, pdf, itext

Estou conseguindo fazer o download do arquivo gerado, mas não consigo setar o nome e nem o .pdf, só faz download como `index.xhtml`.

Alguém sabe como arrumo isso?

Chamo o método para gerar o PDF assim:

```xml
<h:body>
    <h:form>
        <p:panel header="Test Report PDF">
            <p:commandButton value="Report PDF 1 (FileDownload PrimeFaces)" ajax="false">
                <p:fileDownload value="#{reportController.generateReportPDF()}" />
            </p:commandButton>
            <p:commandButton value="Report PDF 2" ajax="false" action="#{reportController.generateReportPDF()}" />
        </p:panel>
    </h:form>   
</h:body>
```

E esta é a forma que gero o PDF:

```
private String reportName = "Report" + day + month + year + ".pdf" ;

public void generateReportPDF() throws DocumentException {
    FacesContext context = FacesContext.getCurrentInstance(); 
    HttpServletResponse response = (HttpServletResponse)context.getExternalContext().getResponse();  
    response.setContentType("application/pdf");  
    response.setHeader("Content-disposition",  "inline=filename=" + reportName);

    Document documentPDF = new Document(PageSize.A4.rotate(), 5f, 5f, 5f, 5f);
    PdfWriter.getInstance(documentPDF, new FileOutputStream(reportName));

    ByteArrayOutputStream baos = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
    PdfWriter.getInstance(documentPDF, baos);

    documentPDF.open();
    documentPDF.add(new Paragraph("Hello World"));
    documentPDF.add(new Paragraph(new Date().toString()));
    documentPDF.close();

    response.setContentLength(baos.size());
    ServletOutputStream os = response.getOutputStream();
    baos.writeTo(os);
    os.flush();
    os.close();
}
```

Comment: Já tentou com o *Content-Disposition* `attachment`? Algo assim: `response.setHeader("Content-Disposition", "attachment; filename=" + reportName);` no lugar de `response.setHeader("Content-disposition",  "inline=filename=" + reportName);`.

Comment: Funcionou... muito obrigado amigo.

Comment: OK, inclui uma resposta para que talvez ajude outras pessoas também

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Apesar de não ser especificação padrão do HTTP, o cabeçalho `Content-Disposition` é documentado por ser amplamente utilizado e busca dizer ao cliente HTTP como o conteúdo que está indo na resposta deve ser tratado.

No caso de conteúdo que são anexos normalmente é utilizado `attachment`, podendo neste caso sugerir um nome para tal anexo, mas o cliente HTTP não é obrigado a utilizar esta sugestão.

Veja a seção [19.5.1](http://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec19.html), onde verá que esta especificação é derivada da contida no [RFC 1806](http://www.ietf.org/rfc/rfc1806.txt), que tratam de mensagem de email, e nela dito a diferença entre os tipos de exibição de conteúdo. Citando de forma breve `inline` e `attachment`:

- Tipo de exibição `inline`:

> A parte da mensagem deve ser marcada como `inline` se é intenção que seja exibida automaticamente após a mensagem principal.

- Tipo de exibição `attachment`:

> Partes da resposta podem ser marcadas como `attachment` para indicar que elas são separadad da parte principal da mensagem e sua exibição não deve ser automática, mas depende de alguma ação do usuário.

No seu caso você está formando o cabeçalho de forma errada, tentando sugerir algo que o cliente provalmente não está entendendo. Como disse que o tipo de conteúdo é `application/pdf` pode ser que o cliente HTTP inferiu que ele deve ser salvo como anexo e, na falta de um nome, usou o nome da página que estava sendo exibida.

Para dizer ao cliente HTTP sua preferência de nome para o arquivo a ser feito download, no lugar deste trecho:

```
response.setHeader("Content-disposition", "inline=filename=" + reportName);
```

Use use este:

```
response.setHeader("Content-Disposition", "attachment; filename=" + reportName);
```

Existem muitas outras RFCs (como [RFC 6266](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc6266)) que tratam desde cabeçalho em específico, caso queira saber mais detalhes basta uma busca rápida na internet =)

Comment: Muito Obrigadoooo

Comment: @Mamga OK, caso tenha sido útil, considere aceitar a resposta :)